# Can surface waves exist near a fixed surface

Tags: waves, geophysics, elasticity, continuum-mechanics

(I'll phrase this question in terms of waves in an elastic medium, but this is a more general question.)

Surface waves are waves near the surface of a medium whose amplitude decreases as you go away from the surface. [Rayleigh waves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_wave) are an example of surface waves in an elastic medium.

From what I understand, Rayleigh waves require a free boundary condition (free as in the end of a string [here](http://www.acs.psu.edu/drussell/Demos/reflect/reflect.html) -- normal derivative of the displacement is zero).

Do analogous surface waves exist for fixed boundary condition? (Fixed meaning that the displacement is zero at the surface -- see previous link.) EDIT: Since the surface is fixed, there can't be waves *at* the surface, but it's conceivable that there are still waves localized *near* the fixed surface. If such waves exist, they would be analogous to Rayleigh waves.

My intuition says no, but I'd like something more concrete -- like a citation.

Comment: Not sure to understand. Let's rephrase a bit: "Surface waves are 'transient displacements' at the surface (...) Do they exist at surfaces with zero displacement?" If this is what you meant, you've got your answer! If you meant otherwise, please clarify.

Comment: I'm curious if there can be waves localized _near_ a fixed surface, not _at_ a fixed surface -- which, as you say, is clearly impossible. ("Near" was in the title, but not the text. I'll edit for clarity.)

Comment: Yes, internal waves in the ocean exist with the rigid lid condition (aka a fixed free surface).  See, for instance, The Dynamics of the Upper Ocean, by OM Phillips (1977).

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason why you couldn't excite waves near a fixed surface, but these won't be surface waves. And if they are travelling close to a fixed surface, there'll be much larger material deformation than in surface waves, thus the attenuation will be strong.